# Image Processing using Java (Min filter); Placing an element in the centre of a 2D matrix

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array, imagefilter

I am trying to implement various image processing filters on a ".pgm" file using java. Below is the code for minimum filter:

```
void applyMinFilter() {
    int [] array = new int[size*size];
    int t = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c<h-size+1; c++) {
        for(int k = 0; k<w-size+1; k++) {
            t = 0;
            for(i = c; i<c+size; i++) { 
                for(j = k; j<k+size; j++) {
                    array[t++] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            //placing the minimum value in the centre of the considered grid
            matrix[i/2][j/2] = minimum(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Here, size = 5, w = h = 400

Using this method, I am getting an output where my desired image is in one corner of the photo. [You can see the output image by clicking here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tffnj.png) In my code, the c loop and k loop help us traverse the whole of the image while the i loop and j loop provide us with the small window that we need to apply the minimum filter. I have already converted the ".pgm" image into a matrix for manipulation.

I am pretty sure that the error is coming from the line just after the comment line. I am not being able to properly place the minimum value pixel at the right location. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the indexing of `matrix[i/2][j/2]` with `matrix[c+size/2][k+size/2]` OR you can make code as below:

```
void applyMinFilter() {
    int [] array = new int[size*size];
    int t = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    // for size = 5 you can use h-2 or w-2
    // to make it general replace with h-size/2 and w-size/2
    for(int c = 2; c < h-2; c++) {
        for(int k = 2; k < w-2; k++) {
            t = 0;
            for(i = c-2; i < c+2; i++) { 
                for(j = k-2; j < k+2; j++) {
                    array[t++] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            //placing the minimum value in the centre of the considered grid
            matrix[c][k] = minimum(array);
        }
    }
}
```